# Drools KnowledgeAgent and Guvnor: authentication fails

Tags: authentication, drools

This one is really driving me nuts.

I have a Guvnor inside JBoss AS (more on versions later). I have edited the components.xml to enable authentication (with JAAS, I have the users and passwords set up just fine) and role based permission. I have an 'admin' user with full privileges and an 'agent' user, with read-only permissions. So far so good, in Guvnor I can see the users and proper privileges, from browsers I can login with the 'admin' user to upload rules and such, and I can download changeset.xmls and binaries with the 'agent' user.

Now, from a Java application I set up a knowledge agent. In the UrlResource, I set up the username ('agent') and password. The changeset downloads just fine, however, the changeset.xml refers to other resources (such as PKG). Downloading them fails (HTTP 401). Seems like Drools forgets about my credentials in the way.

Editing the changeset.xml by hand, and adding enableBasicAuthentcation, username and password - it works fine. But this is not the way to go, really.

I have been looking for either solution: a) see some option panel in Guvnor, so that I can set up what to embed in changeset.xml automatically when deploying packages b) find a way, so the credentials are passed around in my Java project so everything works.

Now, I tried Drools 5.1.1, 5.2.FINAL, 5.3.CR1, looked through the documentation of these versions. The only remark I found was in the 5.3 docs: "The User ID and Password in the change-set should be consistent with the requirements of the Authenticator configured in components.xml." - thank you, I understand, but how to do that? "Please refer to the "Security - Authentication and basic access" section of the "Administration Guide" for more details." I did and found nothing.

So really, what am I missing, or what am I doing wrong? Is really the only way to solve this is not to use authentication? Or edit changeset.xmls by hand at every change?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a workaround posted here

[JBRULES-3465]

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3465

with the constraint it only works for one username per agent

Answer (score 2):

I already got this bug while using KnowledgeAgent, It seems that Url  resources are not set correctly (i'm talking about 5.1.1 version)
As a workaround, you can set up a new Agent Event Listener so force use of username/password this way (it's an inner class in my exemple):

```
    private static final class AuthKnowledgeAgentEventListener extends
        DefaultKnowledgeAgentEventListener {
    private final String username;

    private final String password;

    private AuthKnowledgeAgentEventListener(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeChangeSetApplied(BeforeChangeSetAppliedEvent event) {
        // Obliged to do this to get UrlResources done correctly...
        ChangeSet changeSet = event.getChangeSet();
        for (Resource res : changeSet.getResourcesAdded()) {
            if (res instanceof UrlResource) {
                setupUrlResource((UrlResource) res);
            }
        }
        for (Resource res : changeSet.getResourcesModified()) {
            if (res instanceof UrlResource) {
                setupUrlResource((UrlResource) res);
            }
        }
                        // maybe this is needed for deleted resources, i didn't check

    }

    private void setupUrlResource(UrlResource resource) {
        if (starter.droolsAuthenticationEnabled) {
            resource.setBasicAuthentication("enabled");
            resource.setUsername(username);
            resource.setPassword(password);
        }
    }
}
```

and then you set this event listener to you agent:

```
agent.addEventListener(new AuthKnowledgeAgentEventListener("myusername","mypassword"));
```

And that's it!

Comment: I've exactly tried what you suggested, but unfortunately this only helps to get the changeset.xml, but then afterwards, the agent is not clever enough to reuse the provided credentials for the resource set in the changeset file.

Comment: What is exactly your test case? Because this code aims exactly at updating all url resources in the changeset.xml before download. Did you set the things in this order :  - You set up the agent with the listener  
- You set up the changeSet Url Resource with username and password  
- You apply the change set
This way, it worked perfectly well for me